# How to move .conda from one folder to another at the moment of creating the environment

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I have to connect to a server where my user has access to one small partition from `/home/users/user_name` where I have a quota of limited space and a bigger partition into `/big_partition/users/user`

After I am logging into that server I will arrive at `/home/users/user_name` at the bigging. After that, I am doing the following steps.

1. `cd /big_partition/users/user`
2. `create conda --prefix=envs python=3.6`

on the 4th line, it says `Package plan for installation in environment /big_partition/users/user/envs:` which is ok.

3. press **y**, and not I am getting the following message.

   `OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded: '/home/users/user_name/.conda/envs/.pkgs/python-3.6.2-0/lib/python3.6/unittest/result.py'`

Can anyone help me to understand how can I move the `.conda` folder from `/home/users/user_name` to `/big_partition/users/user` at the moment when I am creating this environment?

Comment: Is this a server that already has a Conda installation?

Comment: Yes it has it already.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Configure Environment and Package Default Locations

I'd guess that, despite your efforts to put your environments on the large partition, there is still a default user-level *package cache* and that is filling up the home partition. At minimum, set up a new [package cache](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-package-directories-pkgs-dirs) and a default [environments directory](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-env-directories) on the large partition:

```bash
# create a new pkgs_dirs (wherever, doesn't have to be hidden)
mkdir -p /big_partition/users/user/.conda/pkgs

# add it to Conda as your default
conda config --add pkgs_dirs /big_partition/users/user/.conda/pkgs

# create a new envs_dirs (again wherever)
mkdir -p /big_partition/users/user/.conda/envs

# add it to Conda as your default
conda config --add envs_dirs /big_partition/users/user/.conda/envs
```

Now you don't have to fuss around with using the `--prefix` flag any more - your *named* environments (`conda create -n foo`) will by default be created inside this directory and you can activate by name instead of directory (`conda activate foo`).

### Transferring Previous Environments and Package Cache

Unfortunately, there's not a great way to move Conda environments across filesystems without destroying the hardlinks. Instead, you'll need to recreate your environments. Since you may or may not want to bother with this, I'm only going to outline it. I can elaborate if needed.

1. **Archive environments.** Use `conda env export -n foo > foo.yaml` (One per environment.)
2. **Move package cache.** Copy contents of old package cache (`/home/users/user_name/.conda/envs/.pkgs/`) to new package cache.
3. **Recreate environments.** Use `conda env create -n foo -f foo.yaml`.

Again, you could just skip this altogether. This is mainly if you want to be very thorough about transferring and not having to redownload stuff for environments you already created.

After this you can delete some the stuff under the old `~/.conda/envs/pkgs` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. All I need to do is to export CONDA_ENVS_PATH with the path where I want to be the `.conda`

`export CONDA_ENVS_PATH=.`

Comment: While this is viable, I would give preference to using the config options (as per my answer) since that's what they're there for. The environment variables are the highest possible execution and I would recommend using them only for *ad hoc* overrides.